# Issue with my SQL delete function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My page displays

> You have an error in your SQL syntax. Check the manual that corresponds to your server version for the right syntax to use at line 2 near '$file'.

Help please..

Here is my code:

```
$file= $_session["note";
$sql="DELETE FROM {$_SESSION   ["group"]}
WHERE file=$file";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quote for string value

```
 "DELETE FROM {$_SESSION["group"]}
  WHERE file='$file';"
```

or previous a proper sanitize of you var you can use string concatenation

```
 "DELETE FROM  "  .$_SESSION["group"] . 
  " WHERE file='" . $file "';"
```